# SQL -- many-to-many query

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to select **all recipes which contain a given number of ingredients**. I'm able to find all recipes based on one given recipe_id
with:

```
SELECT name
FROM recipe
INNER JOIN recipe_ingredient
ON recipe.recipe_id = recipe_ingredient.recipe_id
WHERE recipe_ingredient.recipe_id = ?
```

But I'm having trouble figuring out what the query should look like when I'm looking for recipes which **contain more than contain more than one specific ingredient**. For Example Ingredient A and Ingredient B.

My tables look like this:

```
ingredient
  -ingredient_id
  -name

recipe_ingredient
  -recipe_ingredient
  -ingredient_id
  -recipe_id


recipe
  -recipe_id
  -name
```

I would be very happy about any ideas on how to solve that problem!
Thanks.

Comment: There is a distinction to be made here.  Do you want all Recipes that have more than one ingredient irrespective of which ingredients those are?  Or do you want all recipes that contain specific ingredients?  It's not clear from your question but there are answers to cover both

Comment: You are right, my question was not clear enough. Sorry for that. I'm look for all recipes that contain specific ingredient!

Comment: Ok - I updated my answer based on this comment

Answer (score 0):

Your query will look something like this

```
Your query will look something like this

SELECT name, count(*)
FROM recipe
INNER JOIN recipe_ingredient
ON recipe.recipe_id = recipe_ingredient.recipe_id
GROUP BY name 
HAVING count(*) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to match **all** elements of an `IN` clause, you need to make sure you select only Recipes that have a `count` which matches the total number of Ingredients in your list:

```
SELECT name
FROM recipe
INNER JOIN recipe_ingredient
ON recipe.recipe_id = recipe_ingredient.recipe_id
WHERE recipe_ingredient.ingredient_id IN (ID1, ID2, ID3) --list of ingredient IDs
Group By Name
Having Count(*) = 3 --# of Ingredients you have chosen
```

Good luck finding which recipe will work with the ingredients you have available

[Here is a functional example](http://rextester.com/ACABX67258)

Comment: when I change the last line  `WHERE recipe_ingredient.recipe_id IN (ID1, ID2, ID3)` to `WHERE recipe_ingredient.ingredient_id IN (ID1, ID2, ID3)` it gives me all the recipes that contain at least one of those given IDs! So that is a big step in the right direction for me. But now my question is how to get just those recipes which contain at least all the given ingredients, not just a subset of the given ones.

Comment: @ArtemisUser thanks for pointing out it should be `ingredient_id`.  I just updated the answer to make sure you match ALL elements in the list

Answer (score 0):

IF looking for specific Ingredients, you could do a pre-query doing a union of all the ingredients you are interested in.  Join that to the ingredients table per recipe and make sure that all ingredients are accounted for.  This is handled by the group by and having count = the number of ingredients you are looking for.

I did this example based on the name of the ingredient.  If you have/know the actual ingredient ID (which would be more accurate such as web-based and you have the IDs chosen by a user), just change the join condition to the ingredient ID instead of just the description of the ingredient.

```
SELECT
      r.name,
      r.recipe_id
   from
      ( SELECT 'Milk' as Ingredient
           UNION select 'Eggs'
           UNION select 'Butter' ) as Wanted
         JOIN recipe_ingredient ri
            ON Wanted.Ingredient = ri.recipe_ingredient
            JOIN Recipe r
               ON ri.Recipe_id = r.id
   group by
      ri.recipe_id
   having
      COUNT(*) = 3
```

In this case, Milk, Butter, Eggs and a final count = 3.

Answer (score -1):

Use group by and having clause

```
SELECT name
FROM recipe
INNER JOIN recipe_ingredient
ON recipe.recipe_id = recipe_ingredient.recipe_id
GROUP BY name
HAVING count(1) > 1
```

Comment: Your group by should be on the name. I'm pretty sure this will throw an error as written

Comment: yes, I was thinking same thing, just to simplify query, thanks :)

Answer (score -1):

Just use `OR` for your `where`.
Like this

```
$query = "SELECT name
FROM recipe
INNER JOIN recipe_ingredient
ON recipe.recipe_id = recipe_ingredient.recipe_id
WHERE recipe_ingredient.recipe_id = ? OR recipe_ingredient.recipe_id = ?";
```